# What is the probability distribution the angular component of the electron in the hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, hydrogen, spherical-harmonics

The angular component of the electron in a hydrogen atom is the family of spherical harmonic functions, Y(*θ*,*Φ*). I have seen the angular function probability distribution graphically represented as the modulus squared, |Y(*θ*,*Φ*)|², however I seem to have a misconception.

When you graph the probability distribution of the radial component, R(*r*), of the hydrogen atom, you add the term, *r*² to produce the radial probability distribution function, *r*²R(*r*)² (I presumed you add the *r*² term because the hydrogen atom is in spherical coordinates). Why do you not add the sin(*θ*) term to the angular component to produce the angular probability distribution function, |Y(*θ*,*Φ*)|²sin(*θ*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, |Y(θ,Φ)|²sin(θ) is called the angular distribution function. Since the presence of sin(θ) makes this function zero at the north and south poles, the probability of finding the electron in a surface element located at any of these poles is zero. It may seem strange, but that's how it is. It is unfortunate that textbooks don´t discuss this. You can find graphs of this function in the paper Configuration complexities of hydrogenic atoms, Dehesa et al., Eur. Phys. J. D 55, 539–548 (2009), DOI: 10.1140/epjd/e2009-00251-1.

Comment: The probability *per unit of $\varphi$* is zero, because as you go closer to the pole a given $\Delta \varphi$ occupies less space. This is just a coordinate effect that comes from looking at a probability distribution per unit of $\theta$ and $\phi$; the probability per unit solid angle is not zero at the poles.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  Please use MathJaX (a cousin of LaTeX) to format mathematical expressions on this site.  [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to do this.

Comment: actually the “probability of finding the electron in a surface element located at any of these poles” is not zero but just very small.  The probability is obtained by integration over the surface element and the density is not zero everywhere on that surface element.

Answer (score 1):

… so the probability density $\vert Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)\vert^2\sin\theta$ integrates to 1:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\,\int_0^{\pi} d\theta \vert Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)\vert^2 \sin\theta=1\, .
$$
The extra $\sin\theta$ factor some from the volume element in spherical coordinates:
$$
r^2 \sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi\, .
$$

Comment: Isn't there a $\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi$ missing in your integral?

Comment: What physical significance does |Y(θ,Φ)|² have? It is often used to graph the spherical harmonics.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch fixed thanks.

Comment: You can plot $\vert Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)\vert^2$ just like you an plot $R^2_{n \ell}(r)$, but $\vert Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\phi)\vert^2$ itself has no obvious physical interpretation, no more than $R^2_{n\ell}(r)$.